# Keep messages in ActiveMQ queue if ThreadPoolTaskExecutor has no free capacity

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, spring-integration

I have two Java processes, the first one of them produces messages and puts
them onto an ActiveMQ queue. The second process (consumer) uses Spring
Integration to get messages from the queue and processes them in threads.

I have two requirements:

1. The consumer should have 3 processing threads. If I have 10 messages
   coming in through the queue, I want to have 3 threads processing the first 3
   messages, and the other 7 messages should be buffered.
2. When the consumer stops while some messages are not yet processed, it
   should continue processing the messages after a restart.

Here's my config:

```xml
<bean id="messageActiveMqQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="example.queue" />
</bean>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
    destination="messageActiveMqQueue" channel="incomingMessageChannel" />

<int:channel id="incomingMessageChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="incomingMessageChannelExecutor" />
</int:channel>

<bean id="incomingMessageChannelExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="daemon" value="false" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="3" />
</bean>

<int:service-activator input-channel="incomingMessageChannel"
    ref="myMessageProcessor" method="processMessage" />
```

The first requirement works as expected. I produce 10 messages and 3
myMessageProcessors start processing a message each. As soon as the 1st message has
finished, the 4th message is processed.

However, when I kill the consumer before all messages are processed, those
messages are lost. After a restart, the consumer does not get those messages
again.

I think in the above configuration that's because the threads generated by the
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor queue the messages. So the messages are already removed
from the incomingMessageChannel. Hence I tried setting the queue capacity of
the incomingMessageChannelExecutor:

```xml
<property name="queueCapacity" value="0" />
```

But now I get error messages when I have more than 3 messages:

```
2013-06-12 11:47:52,670 WARN [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] - Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
org.springframework.integration.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'incomingMessageChannel'
```

I also tried changing the `message-driven-channel-adapter` to an `inbound-gateway`,
but this gives me the same error.

Do I have to set an error handler in the `inbound-gateway`, so that the errors go back to the ActiveMQ queue? How do I have to configure the queue so that the messages are kept in the queue if the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor doesn't have a free thread?

Thanks in advance,

Benedikt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; instead of using an executor channel, you should be controlling the concurrency with the `<message-driven-channel-adapter/>`.

Remove the `<dispatcher/>` from the channel and set `concurrent-consumers="3"` on the adapter.

Comment: Thank you very much Gary. Now it works as expected. (I also set the prefetch policy on my queue to 1, http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html)